# Spring : Is there a way to efficiently handling the bean initialization errors?

Tags: spring, jakarta-ee

There is a need where in I want to catch the `exception` occured during spring initialization while server startup and ignore if the cause of `exception` is of `type 'X'` ? Is this possible ?
`lazy-init` is not the option here.....
If i can specify an `onExceptionClass` while defining a bean that would be great or something like that ?

below is the beanId :

```
<bean id="entityManagerFactoryMemberDB"
    class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean" depends-on="addBtsConfiguration,systemPrereqs">
    <property name="persistenceUnitName" value="MemberDBUnit" />
    <property name="dataSource" ref="memberDBDataSource" />
    <property name="jpaVendorAdapter">
        <bean class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.vendor.HibernateJpaVendorAdapter">
            <property name="database" value="${memberDB.jdbc.database}" />
            <property name="showSql" value="${memberDB.hibernate.show_sql}" />
        </bean>
    </property>
```

In this case hibernate tries to get connection to the DB, which for some reason i want to ignore, is it possible ?

Comment: You are sure there is nothing wrong with your wiring and the exception cannot be avoided? Can you share some code?

Comment: edited my question itself as i was not allowed to post answers ...